# Semi-colon expected... but there is one, any MVC.NETers can look at this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected

Source Error:

Line 56:    </div><!--end #Asset-->
Line 57:    
Line 58:         <% KODmvc.Models.AssetRatingViewModel ratingModel = ViewData["RatingViewModel"] as KODmvc.Models.AssetRatingViewModel(); %>
Line 59:        <% Html.RenderPartial("RatingView", ratingModel); %>
Line 60: 

Source File: c:\RatingSystem\Views\Asset\ArticleView.aspx    Line: 58
```

What gives? The semicolon on line 58 IS THERE..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the `as` keyword to cast to a method call.

```
ViewData["RatingViewModel"] as KODmvc.Models.AssetRatingViewModel();
```

Are you sure this is a method, and not a type?  Have you tried removing the parens?

```
ViewData["RatingViewModel"] as KODmvc.Models.AssetRatingViewModel;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<% KODmvc.Models.AssetRatingViewModel ratingModel = ViewData["RatingViewModel"] as KODmvc.Models.AssetRatingViewModel(); %>
```

should be

```
<% KODmvc.Models.AssetRatingViewModel ratingModel = ViewData["RatingViewModel"] as KODmvc.Models.AssetRatingViewModel; %>
```